# REGEX - Patterns showing all the `re` commands

Tags: python, regex

Do you know one big pattern, or several small patterns using all the commands of the `re` pattern syntax ?

This is to do some tests on a function that gives a tree view of a `re` pattern (this tree view is more user friendly than the on given by `sre_parse`).

Comment: You want an expression which uses every regex token available, for testing?

Comment: A single pattern is not necessary indeed. I should use the official doc to build one first example but I know that there are some features not explained in this doc. I have to sleep but tomorow I will give a starting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

This is one regular expression containing all the valid tokens for Python, unless I am mistaken:

`(^|\A)\bthis\t\r\n\a\e\f\v.\u0021\w\W\d\D\s\S[\x00\xBC\xC9\u00C7\w\n!-a]\Bregex*shows+every?token{1,}(?P<that>you can)\1(?=possibly)(?!use)(?<=within)(?<!a single)(?#regular expression in python)(?:\Z|$)`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :-) How did you bluid this pattern ? Have you a special reference ?

Comment: I have a commercial tool called RegexBuddy, it lets me open a menu of all the tokens, and I can create them one by one. For a free reference I would use http://www.regular-expressions.info or http://www.regex101.com